# Adding UI elements into an Xcode created NavigationController Storyboard Scene

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

Storyboarding seems to be pretty interesting, but I am finding it extremely restricting.

I want to use the standard Storyboard for iPhone/iPad Navigation controller/DetailView controllers, but in the iPhone nab controller I also want to ad come controls for status etc.

All the editor seems like it will allow is embedding into a tabview controller.

How can I, for example, resize the navigation controller and add a button/label/whatever underneath?

Comment: You can certainly use storyboards for navigation controllers etc. i'd recommend creating a "Master-Detail Application" and taking a look at the resulting storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

A Nav Bar has some restrictions which you can read about in Apple's class reference for it. One way I have used to put more information in the Navigation Bar with Storyboard is to add a UIBarButton to the NavBar. Grow that with the size inspector to as large as you as want given the size of the Nav Bar, them place a UIView in it and make it as large as the UIBarButton. The UIView can then contain UILabels for status and and UIButtons for actions. Looks like this:

[image: Screen Shot Of UIBarButton containing UIView which contains 2 UILabels and 1 UIButton]

Comment: great looking nav bar!  Googling how to change that background image, thanks!